# smooth approximate parameterization to polygonal boundary

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, intuition

I can "almost" parameterize the boundary of a square using
$${\bf r}(t) = (\cos t)^{1/p} {\bf i} + (\sin t)^{1/p} {\bf j},$$
$0\leq t\leq 2 \pi$, and $p$ is odd. This parameterization is smooth (or at least $C^1$), and of course is the unit ball in the $L^p$ norm. Letting $p\rightarrow \infty$ makes our approximation better.

Now suppose I have a triangle, or in general, a convex polygon with vertices $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$. Is there some relatively simple, explicit smooth approximate parameterization of the boundary? It should, of course, have some tweakable parameter that allows for convergence, like $p$ in the example I gave. The simpler, and the "cuter", the better.

Another issue is the following. With my parameterization of the square, if I want to get a list of roughly equally distributed points on the boundary, I cannot do this by letting $t=2 \pi i/N$. In that case the points collect around the corners on the square. Is there some nice way of fixing this for the square, and for my polygon in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An arc-length parametrization of your polygon uses piecewise-linear functions: if $a_j = (b_j, c_j)$, $r(t) = \sum_j u_j(t) a_j$ where
$u_j(t)$ is a "triangular" function of the form
$$ u_j(t) = \cases{
                   \dfrac{t-t_{j-1}}{t_j - t_{j-1}} & for $t_{j-1} \le t \le t_j$\cr
\dfrac{t_{j+1} - t}{t_{j+1}-t_j} & for $t_j \le t \le t_{j+1}$\cr
0 & otherwise}$$
 You can smooth it out e.g. by replacing $u_j(t)$ by
$$\frac{p}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u_j(s)}{p^2 + (t-s)^2}\ ds$$
for $p \to 0+$.  This is a bit messy, but can be written explicitly using
logarithms and arctan.